# How do I pass multiple columns from a dataframe as individual arguments to a custom function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with variable number of columns. I want to pass

for instance let's say I have the dataframe df and I want to pass columns a and b as individual arguments to my custom function; but the issue is that the list of column names of interest changes depending on the outcome of another operation and could be any lemgth etc.

```
df <- tibble(a = c(1:3), b = c(4:6), c=(7:9), d=c(10:12))
custom_function <- function(...){ do something }
custom_function(df$a, df$b)
```

I haven't found a clean way to achieve this. Any help would be great.

**UPDATE**

for better clarity I need to add that the challenge is the fact the list of columns of interest is retrieved from another variable. for instance `col_names <- c("a","b")`

Comment: @akrun I'm using the ridge function from survival package. If I pass arguments like this : ridge( df$a + df$b) it will add them and return a singular output. If I pass ridge(df[,c(a,b)]) it will return a list which is not usable in regression formula . The only correct way to get the desired output is ridge(df$a, df$b, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can capture the `...` as a `list` can then apply the function within `do.call`

```
custom_function <- function(fn, data = NULL, ...) {

   args <- list(...)
   if(length(args) == 1 && is.character(args[[1]]) && !is.null(data)) {
      args <- data[args[[1]]]
}
  
   
    do.call(fn, args)

}
custom_function(pmax, df$a, df$b)
[1] 4 5 6
```

and we can pass `ridge`

```
> custom_function(ridge, df$a, df$b)
   [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6
attr(,"class")
[1] "coxph.penalty"
...

> custom_function(ridge, data = df, c("a", "b"))
  a b
[1,] 1 4
[2,] 2 5
[3,] 3 6
attr(,"class")
[1] "coxph.penalty"
attr(,"pfun")
...

> custom_function(ridge, data = df, col_names)
     a b
[1,] 1 4
[2,] 2 5
[3,] 3 6
attr(,"class")
...
```

Comment: I think it's getting close to what I need. Imagine if the list of column names is variable though. col_names <- c("a","b") and in another situation it might change to col_names <- c("c","d")

Comment: @SinaFathieh your orignal question showed that it is applied as `df$a, df$b` separately as arguments.  Is that rule changed

Comment: no I might have not explained it properly. That was just an example, but in reality the list of columns of interest is retrieved from another variable

Comment: @SinaFathieh if the column names are passed, then we need the data as well for subsetting?

Comment: yes, so technically each column will need to be treated as individual variables when passed to the function. So the steps are first the column names of interest are stored in a vector. Then each of those columns will need to be passed to the function as separate arguments

Answer (score 3):

If your outcome is a data.frame, a possibility is to use the the curly-curly `tidyverse` operator, using the command `{{}}`, the goal of this operator is to allow us to have an argument passed to our function refering to a column inside a dataframe.

### Data

```
df <- tibble(a = c(1:3), b = c(4:6), c=(7:9), d=c(10:12))
```

### Example

```
library(dplyr)

operations <- function(df,col1,col2){
  df %>% 
    summarise(
      n = n(),
      addition = {{col1}} + {{col2}},
      subtraction = {{col1}} - {{col2}},
      multiplication = {{col1}} * {{col2}},
      division = {{col1}} / {{col2}}
      
    ) 
}
```

### Output

```
operations(df,a,b)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
      n addition subtraction multiplication division
  <int>    <int>       <int>          <int>    <dbl>
1     3        5          -3              4     0.25
2     3        7          -3             10     0.4 
3     3        9          -3             18     0.5
```

Comment: my problem is the list of columns of interest is defined in another variable and is not constant. So i dont know in advance that I need col1 and col2, and i need to retrieve them from another variable which could be any length up to maximum ncol (df)